# Looping through URLs when webscraping tables in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to webscrape tables from the humane society legislative fund. The following code successfully gets the data from one of the pages:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


browser.get('https://hslf.org/scorecards/2007-senate-midterm')
time.sleep(10)


html = browser.page_source

humane_sc_tables = pd.read_html(html)
humane_sc_data = humane_sc_tables[0]
```

I now need to loop through multiple URLs and export each webpage result into a csv file.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import exceptions
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

URL_list = ["https://hslf.org/scorecards/2007-senate-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2008-senate-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2008-house-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2009-senate-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2009-house-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2010-house-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2010-senate-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2011-house-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2011-senate-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2012-house-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2012-senate-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2013-house-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2013-senate-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2014-house-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2014-senate-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2015-house-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2015-senate-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2016-house-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2016-senate-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2017-house-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2017-senate-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2018-house-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2018-senate-final"]

for url in URL_list:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    time.sleep(5)

    print("Current session is {}".format(browser.session_id))
    browser.quit()
    try:
        browser.get(url)
    except exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException as e:
        print(e.message)

    html = browser.page_source
    humane_sc_tables = pd.read_html(html)
    humane_sc_data = humane_sc_tables[0]
    humane_sc_data = humane_sc_data.drop(humane_sc_data.columns[[0,5,7]], axis = 1)
    browser.close()
    humane_sc_data.to_csv(f'humane_scores{url}.csv')
```

However, I get the following error:

> MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=55494): Max
> retries exceeded with url:
> /session/7e430735b2d015147dc20049f3b78b10/url (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x7f9c018aa210>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61]
> Connection refused'))

Please advise.

Comment: A quick google search for that error message returns plenty of results, have you already gone through all of those?

Comment: What is the need for `browser.quit()` before calling the `.get()` method? You sure that's not the root cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to  `browser.quit()` below

```
print("Current session is {}".format(browser.session_id))
browser.quit()
try:
    browser.get(url)
except exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException as e:
    print(e.message)
```

> quit() is a webdriver command which calls the driver.dispose method, which in turn closes all the browser windows and terminates the WebDriver session.

So it seems like you are closing the instance of the browser before making the `.get()` the request which in turn retrieves your desired content. Try adding the line to the end of the loop so that on the next iteration a new session will be created.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. See the code below:

```
import time
import pprint
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

'''

Note:
The link https://hslf.org/scorecards/2007-house-midterm doesn't work 
and is therefore excluded

'''
URL_list = ["https://hslf.org/scorecards/2007-senate-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2008-senate-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2008-house-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2009-senate-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2009-house-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2010-house-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2010-senate-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2011-house-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2011-senate-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2012-house-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2012-senate-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2013-house-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2013-senate-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2014-house-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2014-senate-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2015-house-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2015-senate-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2016-house-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2016-senate-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2017-house-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2017-senate-midterm",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2018-house-final",
            "https://hslf.org/scorecards/2018-senate-final"]

for url in URL_list:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)
    
    html = browser.page_source
    tables = pd.read_html(html)
    tables = pd.concat(tables)
    
    data = tables.iloc[:, [0,2]]
    
    browser.close()
    browser.quit()
    
    filename = url[28:].replace("/","_")
    data.to_csv(filename+'.csv', index=False)
```